# iOS keep gps permission during the session

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, jquery-mobile

My app loads a jquery + google maps file into webview and when viewDidLoad activates an alert asking for gps accessing (as normal). After validating it, if this view is reloaded later, still pushing the alert! how to keep gps permissions in order to avoid multiple alerts asking for permission? Thank you.

Comment: I have had good luck with PhoneGap doing this for me. It overwrites the `navigator.geolocation` object so if you access it, you'll actually be accessing the native GPS functionality rather than Safari's. I don't suggest you go load PhoneGap into your app just for this but maybe you can find a poly-fill or something that helps you do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to access the GPS from native Obj-C code first, and after that let the webview to load:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

This should validate your app to use the GPS, and therefore the Webview to use it (at least if it is a local webview, not sure if it is remote).

Comment: I tried it as you suggest but same result, still pushing the alert :(